# Laravel password encryption/decryption mechanism for ios/android apps

Tags: android, ios, encryption, laravel, cryptography

As I am working in a web application using Laravel - PHP framework. It also have android and ios apps. In web app i'm using Hash::make() for password management and Auth mechanism for login attempt. We have also API for exchanging data between web and mobile apps. How can we encrypt or decrypt password credentials using same Laravel mechanism in android and ios platform.

As I know the password management in Laravel done based on the encryption key provided in the laravel. So how can we encrypt/decrypt same using the same encryption key. Kindly help me on this issue.

Comment: Consider using PBKDF2, it is supported by most systems and is currently recommended by NIST. Common Crypto also has a calibration function to help choose the number of rounds.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel uses a [BCrypt hashing package from Antony Ferrara](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat), so Illuminate\Hashing\BcryptHasher, the implementation of Hash, calls it:

```
$hash = password_hash($value, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => $cost));
```

And since Antony Ferrara follows RFCs, it should be easily reproductible in other platforms. There's a iOS library that might be compatible: [JFCommon](https://github.com/jayfuerstenberg/JFCommon), and you should be able to do it this way:

```
NSString *salt = [JFBCrypt generateSaltWithNumberOfRounds: 10];
NSString *hashedPassword = [JFBCrypt hashPassword: password withSalt: salt];
```

Also, check this article: http://www.jayfuerstenberg.com/blog/bcrypt-in-objective-c

On Android, there are people using this Java lib in their apps: http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/, but I'm not sure that suits to your development needs.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Antoni....Anybody have idea about the same mechanism in android app?

Comment: Edited to provide an option for Android.